# How to get value from list<class> in java?

Tags: java, loops, arraylist

I want to get value from arraylist in java.

I can show traininglist in HTML by using

```
model.addAttribute("traininglist",traininglist);
```

and get the each value by using :

```
tr : ${traininglist}
```

then

```
tr.trainingduration
```

but I now I want to get traininglist value in java, please help me here's my code

```
List<TrainingModel> traininglist = viewTraining(biodataId);
```

and there's my trainingmodel class

```
public class TrainingModel {
    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
    @Column(name="is_delete")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private boolean isDelete;
    @Column(name="biodata_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long biodataId;
    @Column(name="training_name")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private String trainingName;
    @Column(name="organizer")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private String organizer;
    @Column(name="training_year")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private String trainingYear;
    @Column(name="training_month")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private String trainingMonth;
    @Column(name="training_duration")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int trainingDuration;
        //getter setter

}
```

Comment: `TrainingModel tm = traininglist.get( integer );`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To see all the objects in the arrayList, you can use: `System.out.println(traininglist);`

or you can loop through the training list like this:

```
for(TrainingModel listElement : traininglist){
    listElement.(use the getter of any of the fields to get the Object property)
}
```

Hope this helps.